# Bot Programming

Tags: bots

[Screenshot of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMnCb.jpg)

I am trying to write a Bot Program that purpose is to simulate Human accessing the website to make booking.

So basic things is that whenever 7AM, all people start accessing to the website and it makes the booking very difficult.

So I decided to write an automatic bot programming to keep accessing the website until successful (possible with a Timing Parameter on Initial Access like 7AM -0.5MS).

One difficulty is that when accessing, we need to input 3-5 digits verification code from a picture (usually different each time).

So I m thinking whether I should start doing this project using JavaScript or Node.JS.

I programmed C# before, so web programming is completely new.

That's why I wanna ask you guys what kind of language I should use, and is there any reference material or article you can share?

Thanks and Warm regards,
Wilson

Website link: https://w1.leisurelink.lcsd.gov.hk/leisurelink/application/checkCode.do?flowId=2&lang=EN

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

well i would recommend using [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) its fairly simple to use, basically get your main function going with whatever you want to do and put a timeout on it, you can get Local time to start code execution at 7:00 and keep executing either until u get what u want out of it or say until the loop reaches 150-200 attempts

Comment: Thank you my friend. Would you have please any recommendations to the Verification Code Recognition?

Comment: you mean captcha ? if its the just click type puppeteer has in-built captcha solver 
if it has images / text u need to either use 2captcha or some other captcha solving service they are usually pr cheap